# Arduino Charset or Java InputStream Charset cause wrong data?

Tags: android, utf-8, arduino

Recently I use an WIFI mode on Arduino to send data to Android devices,but it can't show the right data I want.

On the Arduino Serial,it's `A中国.GCO` and it's right.But on the Android it's `A�й�~1.GCO`,but I want `A中国.GCO` in Android.

I know the charset on Arduino is `UTF-8`,the Android program's charset is `UTF-8`.I guess maybe the inputstream on Java I get cause it,but I don't konw how to do.

Can someone help?Here Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are sending your data as ASCII characters (1 byte), instead of Unicode UTF-8 (2 bytes).

Comment: I have see the java's `InputStreamReader`,it's charset is `UTF-8`,so the charset using for send is `UTF-8` on Arduino.So why both are `UTF-8`,still get wrong data.

Comment: Finally I found that the charset the Arduino board using for sending data is  `gbk`,So I convert the `InputStreamReader` charset to `gbk` and solve the problem.
But I really don't know why,because `gbk` is a kind of Chinese charset.It confuses me.

Comment: I guess that `A中国.GCO` is "a kind of Chinese". Or isn't it?